# how to select number of records for column in one table

Tags: sql, select, subquery, union

i have table structure like this:

```
  id - person_name - date

- 1 - Tester - 15-10-2014 
- 2 - Tester - 15-10-2014
- 3 - Tester - 15-09-2014
- 4 - Coder  - 15-10-2014
```

I need to select person and for each person min. 3 months with count of records.

Like: name => tester; month1 => 2; month2 => 1;; name => COder; month1 => 1; month2 => 0

```
SELECT person_name, 
       COUNT(person_name) AS month1
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(date) = "10" GROUP BY person_name
```

This gives me good result, like name => Test; month1 => 2 ... but i need also other select to select other month, i tried union and so on, withou any success. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get all the months and all the people, you need a more complicated query.  Start with all the rows you need generated, then use `left join` and `group by`:

```
select n.person_name, ym.y, ym.m, count(t.person_name)
from (select distinct person_name from table) n cross join
     (select distinct year(date) as y, month(date) as m from table) ym left join
     table t
     on t.person_name = n.person_name and year(t.date) = ym.y and month(t.date) = ym.m
group by n.person_name, ym.y, ym.m;
```

Comment: thanks, works nice but the any option how to get months for one persion_name in one row ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you jst need to group on month as well and exampled the filer. Along the lines of:

```
SELECT person_id
      ,MONTH(date)
      ,COUNT(person_id)
  FROM table
 WHERE MONTH(date) IN (8,9,10)
 GROUP BY person_id
         ,MONTH(date)
```

[EDIT] with pivot.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT person_id
             , MONTH(dttm) MonthId 
          FROM tbl) SourceTable     
 PIVOT (COUNT(MonthId) 
          FOR MonthId IN ([8],[9],[10])
       ) PivotTable
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works well, anyway i get employee_name => Tester; month => 9; count => 1 ;;; employee_name => Tester; month => 10; count => 2... any option to get it in one row ? I would like not to use concat...

Comment: It would help if you showed a formated example result set in the question. I *think* your asking to PIVOT the result set my answer would provide. I'll add an edit.